# TFS 2010 - restrict ability to customize Work Item Template

Tags: tfs, permissions

Is there any way to remove the ability for members of the Project Administrator group from being able to modify the Work Item Type Definitions in their projects?

If I were to create a custom group that mimics project administrators (contains the sames permissions), which permission or permissions would need to be denied?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help:

[Manage process template permission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms252587%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Collection)

Users who have this permission can download, create, edit, and upload process templates to the team project collection.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure how that permission restricts the ability to customize a work item template (i.e. Bug, PBI, etc.).

Comment: I was able to apply this in our test environment and it provided the desired result. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think this only works at the collection template level.  Not at the individual project template instance level.